# Hide a EditText & make it visible in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I am making an android app that will send a  id_user and id_status to a remote database with an AsyncTask. If success == 1, then the EditText and button will be visible automatically.

CommentActivity

```
package com.portalalumni;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CommentActivity extends Activity {

SessionManager session;
boolean isVisible;

    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // Creating JSON Parser object 
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // url  
        private static String url_cek_pendidikan = "http://192.168.43.13/alumni/cek_pendidikan.php";

        // JSON Node names
        public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; 

        String id_user,email,id_status;
        private EditText comment;
        Button btnAddComment;

        private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        session.checkLogin();

        //Hashmap from login
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        id_user = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_IDUSER);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
            id_status = extras.getString("id_status");
        }

        // Loading status and comment in Background Thread
        new LoadCekPenddkActivity().execute();

        comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);

        btnAddComment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dm_send);

        // button click event
        btnAddComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating comment in background thread
                new LoadUpdateActivity().execute();

                //comment.getText().clear();
            }
        });

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    public void Set_Visibility_Visible(){
        this.isVisible = true;
    }

    class LoadCekPenddkActivity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CommentActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();*/
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) { 
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_user", id_user));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_status", id_status));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_cek_pendidikan,"GET", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Update", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    comment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    comment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            //pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

After adding the timer task and timer I run the code. The app crashed and I got the following logcat error:

```
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:3939)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:701)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.requestLayout(DrawerLayout.java:762)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:6659)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:4564)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at com.portalalumni.CommentActivity$LoadCekPenddkActivity.doInBackground(CommentActivity.java:521)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at com.portalalumni.CommentActivity$LoadCekPenddkActivity.doInBackground(CommentActivity.java:1)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-23 22:15:34.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     ... 5 more
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050): Activity com.portalalumni.CommentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41439380 that was originally added here
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.portalalumni.CommentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41439380 that was originally added here
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:343)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:245)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at com.portalalumni.CommentActivity$LoadCekPenddkActivity.onPreExecute(CommentActivity.java:497)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at com.portalalumni.CommentActivity.onCreate(CommentActivity.java:105)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-23 22:15:35.999: E/WindowManager(1050):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050): Activity com.portalalumni.CommentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4145bd68 that was originally added here
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.portalalumni.CommentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4145bd68 that was originally added here
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:343)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:245)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at com.portalalumni.CommentActivity$LoadStatusActivity.onPreExecute(CommentActivity.java:228)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at com.portalalumni.CommentActivity.onCreate(CommentActivity.java:106)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-23 22:15:36.149: E/WindowManager(1050):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackground()` runs in a separate thread so you can't touch `View`s of your main `Activity` inside it, that's why you're seeing that `CalledFromWrongThreadException`. Instead, you can call this in *any* method of your `AsyncTask` but `doInBackground()`.

As it seems that you're testing a result of something, I recommend setting this in your `onPostExecute()` method as this will be the next called once you get out of your `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: You're welcome. As I see you haven't accepted answer from your questions, you can help other users which have the same doubt as you by accepting the answer that helped you most. You can do this checking the 'tick' under the points of the answer you want to choose, this way they'll know that was the most helpful. This is *not* obliged, but it's recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to update the UI in the `doInBackground()` method. Move the update UI part to `onPostExecute()` method like following,

```
             if (success == 1) {
                    comment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    comment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: @Kasih:well you can accept and upvote this answer if it helps so that others will be aware of it.